# In php, what does it mean to enclose a function call inside parenthesis?

Tags: php

In the framework I'm working in, Phpfox, I see this function invocation signature throughout:

```
(($sPlugin0 = Phpfox_Plugin::get('user.service_user_isuser')) ? eval($sPlugin1) : false);
```

I see no apparent purpose of the outer parenthesis since:

1. `$sPlugin1` is read from enclosing scope and
2. `$sPlugin0` is passed to enclosing scope after being assigned.

What is the purpose of the outer parens? What I'm getting at is is there some functional aspect to the outer parens like in Javascript?

Updated:
I know that outer parens would be meaningless in an expression such as

(1 + 1)

that's not what I'm asking.

I now conclude as I suspected that in php these outer parens do nothing.

Thanks

Comment: It's meaningless and doesn't do anything.

Comment: The ternary conditional seems likewise pointless. An empty string would satisfy `eval`.

Comment: great are the mysteries of some framework developers

Comment: Aside from grouping codes to make it a bit readable, it doesn't do anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, Its meaningless and doesn't do anything. Just like in math where we do

```
( 1 + 2 )
```

or even

```
((1) + (2))
```

Parenthesis use to indicate precedence(which helps in identifying which one will be evaluate first). It only changes when there are more operations next to it:

```
( 1 + 2 ) * 2
```

Again outer parenthesis doesn't do anything in below case

```
(( 1 + 2 ) * 2)
```

Comment: You're missing the point, though I didn't explain it directly. But my comments about scope should have been a clue that I was getting at scope and the functional aspects of the language. In Javascript the outer parens do have meaning. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeMakkuch Sorry dude. Its just hard to post an answer that only contains "Nothing". I know that you do know how to use parenthesis. Sorry again and didn't mean to offend or imply other bad things